# Execute/Call a script file from inside of an imacro file

Tags: vbscript, imacros

I have a visual basic script file which needs to be called in an imacro file. Is that possible? If yes, could anybody please provide an example ! Badly in search of the answer :(

Thanks in advance !! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I gleaned from the [documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page) that doesn't seem to be possible. You can run `imacros` code from VBScript, and you can run JavaScript code from a macro via `EVAL`, but you cannot run external VBScripts from `imacros`.